# How to handle #ERROR, NAN and INFINITY in a single expression in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

So, if current and previous both are blank then I need to show result also blank. My Formula looks like this (Current-Previous)/Previous*100

I tried like this

=IIF((SUM(Current)= "" OR SUM(Previous) = ""),"",(SUM(Current) - SUM(Previous))) / SUM(Previous)

but it was giving #ERROR, NAN and INFINITY I want solution for all these issues in a single expression. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

This is a well documented issue with SSRS. It evaluates both sides of the iif so it always ends up with divide by zero errors if it encounters one.

One way to handle it is through vb code in your report.

Go to report properties -> Code

Paste the following code :

```
Public Shared Function divbyzero(ByVal Standard As Decimal, ByVal Actual As Decimal) As Decimal
If Actual = 0 Then
Return 0
End If
If Standard = 0 Then
Return 0
End If
Return (Standard / Actual )
End Function
```

The above function will return a zero if either a numerator or the denominator is a zero.

Now on your report, go to the text box where you are performing your equation and do the following instead.

```
=code.divbyzero(SUM(fields!Current.value) - SUM(fields!Previous.value) ,SUM(fields!Previous.value))
```